# Polygon detect from layer

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

Need to grab all polygons from Png images(map layers).

[image: Map layer]

After searching, I found OpenCV. Who faced similiar, can you tell is OpenCV correct instrument for these task?

Comment: what do you mean by polygons? the green lines? and what do you exactly need to "grab"?
Do you want to mask the image for only the green lines or do you need the pixel coordinates of the path corners?

Comment: @DavidSalb Need green lines and blue polygons coorfdinates